# Should I only setup Keycloak on application OR Apache

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I would like to check if my understanding is correct about the way to use Keycloak.

After Keycloak server is installed and running, we would have 2 options:

1. Use the `javascript adapter` in the application we want to authenticate
2. Use the `mod_auth_openid` to use Keycloak with Apache webserver

In the case of web application, since it must have an web server, does it mean only option 2 is available? And even if option 1 is available, should I use it?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of your application. If you want to provide your application as SPA (Single Page Application) using JavaScript, `JavaScript Adapter` will be good option. But if you want to provide it as traditional server-side web application which doesn't support standard federation protocol like OpenID Connect, `mod_auth_openidc` will fit. 
Also keycloak provides several types of client adapters. You can check them with the following document.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#supported-platforms

In addition, if your application is already OpenID Connect or SAML 2.0 compliant, you can integrate with keycloak server without any client adapters because it based on open standard protocol which keycloak supports. Please refer the following document to understand securing your application.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#overview

Comment: I would also point out that the JS adapter is not the only way to develop an SPA. You could still have an SPA and rely in some server side adapter.